# How to save field from ManyToMany relationship? Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have 2 entities, InProveedorProducto which has a id_producto field and InOrdenCompraDetalle which has a detail of a purchase order, including id_producto field too. InProveedorProducto in a table which has id_producto but also id_proveedor, that means that this table contains a list of products for each provider.

So, my TYPE form:

```
class InOrdenCompraDetalleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    protected $idProveedor;

    protected $idEmpresaa;

    public function __construct ($id_proveedor,$id_empresaa)
    {
        $this->idProveedor = $id_proveedor;
        $this->idEmpresaa = $id_empresaa;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ordenCompra')
            ->add('productoOc', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'NivalInventarioBundle:InProveedorProducto',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.idProveedor = '.$this->idProveedor)
                        ->orderBy('u.productoO', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => function ($displayname) {
                                    return $displayname->getDisplayName();},
                'by_reference' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opción',
                'mapped' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
            ))
            ->add('cantidad');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Nival\InventarioBundle\Entity\InOrdenCompraDetalle'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'nival_inventariobundle_inordencompradetalle';
    }

 }
```

My entity InProveedorProducto

```
class InProveedorProducto
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="InOrdenCompraDetalle", inversedBy="productoOc")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="InCompraDetalleProveedorProducto")
     */
    protected $producto;
```

My entity InOrdenCompraDetalle

```
lass InOrdenCompraDetalle
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMAny(targetEntity="InProveedorProducto", mappedBy="producto")
     */
    protected $productoOc;
```

Could you please let me know why i get this error when try to save to database:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\nival7\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 555 and defined
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you forgot to do this in your `__constructor()`

```
class InProveedorProducto {
   public function __construct(){
      $this->producto = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
   }
}


class InOrdenCompraDetalle {
   public function __construct(){
      $this->productoOc = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
   }
}
```